# How do I dynamically update a DOM element after an AJAX request if not using a `.js.erb`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

So I have a link/button that looks like this in my helper class:

```
link_to "UnFav", unfavorite_node_path(node), class: "btn btn-success favorite", method: :post, remote: true,  data: { toggle_text: 'Fav', toggle_href: favorite_node_path(node), id: node.id }
```

That calls these methods in my controller:

```
  def favorite
    @node.liked_by current_user

    if request.xhr?
      render json: { count: @node.get_likes.size, id: params[:id] }
    else
      redirect_to @node
    end
  end

  def unfavorite
    @node.unliked_by current_user
    if request.xhr?
      render json: { count: @node.get_likes.size, id: params[:id] }
    else
      redirect_to @node
    end
  end
```

I am using [acts-as-votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable).

In my view, I show the number of votes on a particular `node` like this:

```
<span class="card-favorite-count">
   <i class="icon-heart"></i> <%= node.cached_votes_total %>          
</span>
```

Ideally, what I want to happen is, when one of those links are pressed, and the action is successfully executed, I want to update the count that is already being shown in the DOM.

I tried creating a `favorite.js.erb` and putting this in it:

```
$(".card-favorite-count").html('<%= node.cached_votes_total %>');
```

But I realized that when I favorited & unfavorited an item, in my server logs it never ever called that `favorite.js.erb` template - so this never gets executed.

I was also looking for a callback on the gem, but I can't find any.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Actually you are rendering `json` in response instead of `js` that is why your `js.erb` is not being called

Comment: Good point. Would I need to change my form or anything if I change from `JSON` to `JS`?

Comment: Are you using that `json` values anywhere?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I don't think so.

Comment: Try the answer code then or I think you know about `js` requests so you know what needs to be done there. So you can check out if there are any issues changing that or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render your file `favorite.js.erb` you need to do:

```
  def favorite
    @node.liked_by current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html{ redirect_to @node }
      end
    end
  end
```

I think the `if` block would not be necessary still unsure but you can try the above code. It would respond with the `js.erb` when it is a js request and when it html request it will redirect.

Comment: Yep this works. I have to rejig a bunch of stuff, but thanks!